# ASP.NET-Core MVC - How to send jwt token when user click on url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I have user that just logged in and has his token(e.g in cookie for a while), but now I have to use it whenever user click on link that requires being `[Authorize]`

e.g I have to send it in HTTP header:

> Authorization: Bearer {token}

But how can I achieve adding HTTP Header to every of his request just from simple View (with Razor)?

I have to overwrite 
[`Challenge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.challengeresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method that's being Invoked when I try to reach `[Authorize]` endpoint or something like that?

Comment: clicking a link is done in the browser. The browser would only make a GET request and wouldn't send HTTP headers when a link is clicked. If you really want to send the token on click, you will have to pass it as a get parameter (i wouldn't recommend). As long as the authorization is present in the current user's cookie, he must be already be authorized when he clicks on the link.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Well, so how can it be done in pure MVC while returning Views instead of data jsons?

Comment: i don't follow your current setup. It seems you are setting up a website (trying to use razor) but you mentioned passing an HTTP header. How are you passing an HTTP header? You cant do this directly in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

it might be a solution to create an eventlistener on the middle like that

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    const origin = e.target.closest('a');
    if (origin) {
        function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"));
        }
    }
}, false);
```